# Convert ERB template to SLIM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Many of my views are SLIM templates and I wish to add a `vote_form` partial to my app. How would I convert this partial view from ERB to SLIM?

```
<strong class="result">Votes: <%= voteable.votes_for - voteable.votes_against %></strong>
<%= form_tag user_votes_path(current_user) do |f| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :up %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :down %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :voteable, @voteable %>
  <%= submit_tag :vote %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Check out http://html2slim.herokuapp.com/

Comment: This is online tool help you to do work fast http://erb2slim.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 29):

## How convert your .erb to .slim :

## Update (18-08-2015)

You can simply use [html2slim](https://rubygems.org/gems/html2slim) gem

```
gem install html2slim
```

This package include a tool called `erb2slim` which can convert erb file to slim recursively. Option `-d` for delete the erb file after the convert finished.

```
erb2slim -d <dir of your views>
```

[View on devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views)

## Original answer

You must pass through *HAML* !

Install *HAML* dependencies on your environment or your gemset

```
gem install html2haml # This was moved out of haml gem
gem install ruby_parser
```

Switch to *HAML* templating

```
find . -name '*erb' | \
xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "html2haml -r #{i} #{i.sub(/erb$/,"haml")}"}' | \
bash
```

Install *SLIM* tool dependency

```
gem install haml2slim # https://github.com/fredwu/haml2slim
```

Switch to *SLIM* templating

```
find . -name '*haml' | \
xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "haml2slim #{i} #{i.sub(/haml$/,"slim")}"}' | \
bash
```

Clean *ERB* and *HAML* templates

```
find . -name '*erb' -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -name '*haml' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Remove dependencies

```
gem uninstall html2haml
gem uninstall ruby_parser
gem uninstall haml2slim
```

That all, have fun

Comment: I had to convert all erb templates to slim in some project, and wow! Your tiny script is soo helpful!! :-) Thank you sir!

Comment: awesome. Just one tip if you are using mac `find . -name '*haml' | xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "haml2slim #{i} #{i.sub(/haml$/,"slim")}"}' | sh`  .. make it single line and use sh

Comment: "You must pass through HAML ! "
Why?

Comment: note for rails 4 and as of 2014 sept: you don't need `haml` gem itself, and you don't need `hpricot` gem when converting. It is enough to have `ruby_parser`, `html2haml`, and `haml2slim` for converting existing files. To have future views to be generated in slim, simply use `slim-rails` gem, and your views will be in slim whenever you run generators.

Also, you can use gemfiles and run bundle, rather than `gem uninstall yourgem`

Comment: I did some modifications based on your original answer. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26073207/784318. Thanks for the original script

Comment: I'm using rails 4. I tried this, and got all the .slim files instead of the erb ones as they were all deleted but now, im getting the missing template error... To convert from ERB to Slim is there anything else I need to know besides changing the views files for a RoR app? Thanks.

Comment: The last version (0.8.0) of haml-rails provide rake haml:erb2haml for the first part and obviously you're under rails app.

Answer (score 6):

Here you are, just paste the erb code and hit 'go':
http://html2slim.herokuapp.com/

Comment: good for short stuff. But if you want to do all your files in your entire project, a tool for mass conversion is needed not only to convert code, but to rename files without having to do it manually.

Comment: And to have future generated templates be in slim.

Answer (score 6):

I like the de facto answer but thought people would love to know about a new gem which does this much faster and with less hassle. It is at the moment however fairly buggy. :(

Check out [html2slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/wiki/Template-Converters-ERB-to-SLIM#using-html2slim). Say I want to change all my views from `.erb` to `.slim`, then I run (from scratch, and from your rails root directory) the following:

```
gem install html2slim
erb2slim app/views --delete
```

If you run `erb2slim -h` you can see that `-d`/`--delete` is an option to delete the erbs afterwards and `--trace` shows a full traceback on any errors. A note from the author that it is still experimental.

Answer (score 6):

This is based on @Joel's brilliant answer. I had to modify it a bit since some gems seem to have moved and I made some other improvements:

- It is all one script so just copy paste
- Don't delete the gems at the end, since I will likely need this for the next project (e.g. when I create devise's views)
- The `gem install ...` portion can then be emitted to make for faster processing.

#### Converting the files

**Update**: The conversion through haml is no longer required. This is the updated script:

```
#### gem install html2slim # this will install `erb2slim` command line tool.
find . -name '*erb' | \
xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "erb2slim #{i} #{i.sub(/erb$/,"slim")}"}' | \
bash

# Clean ERB templates
find . -name '*erb' -exec rm -f {} \;
git add app/views/*
git commit -m "Replace erb with slim"
```

#### The result

In my example (after running `rails g devise:views`)all the `.erb` files were replaced with `.slim` files and then deleted:

[image: Screenshot]

#### The alternative for single files

Sometimes I just wan to convert a snipped. Like it was mentioned before. In such cases I use

https://html2slim.herokuapp.com

[image: html2slim-in-action]

#### The old approach

So here we go:

```
# You must pass through HAML !
# Install HAML dependencies on your environment or your gemset
gem install haml html2haml hpricot ruby_parser haml2slim

# Switch to HAML templating
find . -name '*erb' | \
xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "html2haml -r #{i} #{i.sub(/erb$/,"haml")}"}' | \
bash

#Switch to SLIM templating
find . -name '*haml' | \
xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "haml2slim #{i} #{i.sub(/haml$/,"slim")}"}' | \
bash

# Clean ERB and HAML templates
find . -name '*erb' -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -name '*haml' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply rename the file to end with `.html.slim` instead of `.html.erb`, and replace the content with something like the following:

```rb
strong.result= "Votes: #{voteable.votes_for - voteable.votes_against}"

= form_tag user_votes_path(current_user) do
  = radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :up
  = radio_button_tag :thumb_direction, :down
  = hidden_field_tag :voteable, @voteable
  = submit_tag :vote
```

Answer (score 0):

This is online tool does exactly what you want http://erb2slim.herokuapp.com is convert erb snippets to slim.

Answer (score 0):

As in previous answers I use two gems:

```
 gem install html2haml haml2slim
```

Then:

```
 find app/views -name \*.erb -print | sed 'p;s/.erb$/.haml/' | xargs -n2 sh -c 'html2haml "$0" "$1" && rm "$0"'
```

to replace `*.erb` with converted `*.haml` versions.

Now to convert `*.haml` to `*.slim` and remove `*.haml` files:

```
 haml2slim -d app/views
```

After all optionally:

```
 gem uninstall html2haml haml2slim
```