# How to generate new view files in slim (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, haml, generator, slim-lang

I want newly generated files to be generated in slim, not html.erb

I've converted existing files to slim, but newly generated files aren't being generated in slim.
How can I make it so that newly generated files are in slim?

I've already followed the process outlined here
https://github.com/slim-template/slim/wiki/Template-Converters-ERB-to-SLIM
and here
[Convert ERB template to SLIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347572/convert-erb-template-to-slim)

Newly created files using haml-rails and html2haml get generated in haml properly.
But I want this behavior for slim and html2slim as well.

Comment: The gems should eg slim-rails. That's all you need as far as generating new files as slim. Conversion requires the other gems in the OP links

The accepted answer of this post solves it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455801/ruby-on-rails-make-slim-the-default-template?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing all the necessary steps to convert, just use the slim-rails gem.

Both the slim-rails gem and the haml-rails gem handle newly generated templates being properly converted to the desired preprocessor language.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace gem `'slim'` with gem `'slim-rails'` in your Gemfile.

And also you can set slime as default generator in `config/application.rb`:

```
 config.generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :slim
  end
```